# How to compile python, QT5 app and create single app custom raspberry ISO

Tags: python, yocto, raspbian, buildroot

I have written a small program in python and QT5. I want it on raspberry PI as a single application. I have checked out buildroot and yocto but can't seems to find a single tutorial which can explain the steps from compiling the python code and make it part of buildroot/yocto. Can anyone please guide me or point me to a tutorial.

Regards,

Comment: You do not compile Python code. You would need to copy the file to the image via some means. I believe that buildroot has directory for that (can't remember).

Comment: could try [pyinstaller](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/)

Answer (score 1):

In Buildroot, there are two ways that you can add your own Python code to the build.

1. Using [a root filesystem overlay](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#rootfs-custom) to add you python files in the appropriate place in the root filesystem. This has a lot of limitations though: it doesn't get byte-compiled, you have to make sure yourself that it gets installed in some location in `PYTHONPATH`, and generally it's a bit more difficult to maintain. However, it's a very simple approach for a first try.
2. Creating a [custom python package](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#_infrastructure_for_python_packages). It's also not really complicated to do that, but you really do have to read the documentation.